# Pulling data into a second script using a "more info" button from first script

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm not entirely sure I'm even asking this correctly. I have a lack of terminology, and I apologize for that up front. You see, I have two php scripts, and I'm trying to learn how php and MySQL work together. In my first php script, order.php, I pull information from my database and display it on the page. Under each item that is pulled, there is a "more info" button. My goal is to have a user click on "more info" for any particular item, and when they do, be redirected to a new page that lists THAT items information.

So far, I have the "more info" button linking to a moreinfo.php script, and it is retrieving THAT items description using urlencode, and displaying it on moreinfo.php.

What I need, is to have the "more info" button on "order.php" pull THAT items description, name, and price.

I've tried adding:

```
. urlencode($row['description']) . urlencode($row['price']) .
```

to the code below, and it pulls in the information, but I can't separate it. Here is my code for everything so far.

```
require("database.php"); //connect to the database

$start = (isset($_GET['start']) ? (int)$_GET['start'] : 0); //setting the get function to a variable so I can display data on same page

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM menuitem LIMIT $start, 3");
    if (!$result) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
        exit();
    }

echo "<table width='1024' border='0' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='5' align='center'>
<tr align='center'>
<th></th>
<th>Menu Items</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Add to Order</th>
</tr>";

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
 {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td align='center'><img height='100' width='100' src=\"" . $row['picturepath'] . "\" /></td>"; 

  echo '<td align="center">' . $row['name'] . '</td>';
  /*echo '<td align="center"><input type="button" value="More Info" onclick="window.location=\'more_info.php?start=' . urlencode($row['description']) .' \';" /></td>';*/
  echo '<td align="center"><input type="button" value="More Info" onclick="window.location=\'more_info.php?start=' . urlencode($row['description']) . urlencode($row['price']) .' \';" /></td>';

  echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['price'] . "</td> <td align='center'> <input type='button' value='Add to Order' onclick=''> </td>";
  echo "</tr>";
 }
echo "</table>";
```

Currently, it is pulling the description and price together, and I have no idea how to separate into different tables. If anyone can even give me a keyword to google, I would gladly look up the info on my own, or do whatever I can to research it to get it working.

Here is the moreinfo.php

```
$start = (!empty($_GET['start']) ? $_GET['start'] : false);

<html><table width='100%' border='0'><tr><td height="200"></td></tr></table></html>

<?php
echo "<table width='90%' border='0' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='5' align='center'>"
echo "<tr align='center'>
      <td width='60%' align='left'>" . $start . "</td>
      <td width='40%' align='left'>" "</td>
      </tr>";
echo "</table>"; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at how other sites do the same thing. IE StackOverflow. On the main page, there is a list of questions. When you click a question, that question appears and all data associated with it.

The link to this particular question is `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20622290`.

The number at the end of the URL is this questions ID in the database, or some numerical representation of this question anyways.

I would suggest adding the ID of your item to the end of your URLs. IE, `http://example.com/moreinfo.php?id=5`.

Where `5` is the ID of that item you want to see. This will allow you to grab that items information from the database and you will be able to display it.